# class framePackage.DrawMapTile$1 vs class framePackage.DrawMapTile

Tags: java, instance, equals

So I'm starting to learn Java right now and am working on a project where I have a command handler (nothing fancy just a .sendCommand(String command, Object source))

now I call this sendCommand from a JPanel:

```
public String sendCommand(String command, Object source) {
    String result = "";
    System.out.println(source);
    System.out.println(source.getClass() + " vs "+ DrawMapTile.class);
    System.out.println(source.getClass().isInstance(DrawMapTile.class));
    System.out.println(source.equals(DrawMapTile.class));
    
    if(source.getClass().equals(DrawMapTile.class)) {
        result = drawMapTileCommands(command,(DrawMapTile) source);
    }
    return result;
}
```

and output is:

> framePackage.DrawMapTile$1@2179ea42
>
> class framePackage.DrawMapTile$1 vs class framePackage.DrawMapTile
>
> false
>
> false

What is with the $1 and why is it?

Edit requested:

```
public DrawMapTile(ObjectMap objectMap,int xOfTile, int yOfTile, MainJFrame mainJFrame, DrawMap drawMap) {
    this.mainJFrame = mainJFrame;
    this.objectMap = objectMap;
    this.map = objectMap.getMap();
    this.drawMap = drawMap;
    this.mapTile = map[xOfTile][yOfTile];
    this.color = mapTile.getMapTileType().getColor();
    listener = new ArrayList<ActionListener>();
    drawMapTileActionListener = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            String result = mainJFrame.getCommandHandler().sendCommand(evt.getActionCommand(),this);
            System.out.println(result);
            };
    };
    this.addActionListener(getDrawMapTileActionListener());
}
private ActionListener getDrawMapTileActionListener() {
    return drawMapTileActionListener;
}
```

EDIT 2: I realized what you meant, this is how I solved it now:

```
public String sendCommand(String command, DrawMapTile source) {
    String result = drawMapTileCommands(command, source);
    return result;
}
public String sendCommand(String command, Object source) 
    String result = "";
    return result;
}
```

It now calls what I want to.

Comment: That denotes an anonymous inner class. If you show us the full code, including the part where your method is being called, that would help to explain it further.

Comment: https://github.com/LucaKleck/est-luca-timo/tree/workingBranch All the code If you want to take a look

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That denotes an anonymous inner class. If you show us the full code, including the part where your method is being called, that would help to explain it further.

Seeing that you call it "from a JPanel", the anonymous inner class in question is probably an ActionListener

Comment: What do you want to do? Using an anonymous inner class for an ActionListener is not bad at all, it's standard practice.

Comment: https://github.com/LucaKleck/est-luca-timo/blob/workingBranch/Schulprojekt/src/framePackage/DrawMapTile.java

Comment: I want to call the sendCommand from different places, so It needs to test where it comes from, from that I call the command handler of that class, I want my commands to be all in one place.
Edit: And right now when I test if the class equals the one I check for, it returns false, question is why? Is it because the action listener is it's own thing, if yes, how do I get out of it?

Comment: That sounds like you want your source parameter to implement some kind of callback interface.

Comment: like a method that returns the class it's from? Will try that, thanks!

Comment: No, not like that at all. Just exposing some kind of CommandHandler interface. I don't see what all this inspection of class objects is supposed to achieve. I can't really give you more specific advice without a more specific question.

Comment: Well, I need to cast the source to different kinds of classes, depending on the class they are from, so I want to check what class they are, then cast it to that.

Comment: You know what, I just realized I can just add another String that tells me where it's from... Thanks for the help anyways!

Comment: They still sounds very unnecessary. If a simple callback interface isn't enough, you might want to look into the visitor pattern. Using getClass and casts indicates you're not making use of polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks for your help, avoided making it more complicated than it needed to be.